# accessing static class variables with robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to access static class variables from a library loaded into robot framework?

For example, say I include the following python library in my .robot file:

```
foo = 'value'

class MyClass(self):
    bar = 'value'
```

Is there a way in the .robot file that included it to refer to foo or bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get at these by getting a reference to the raw python module with [Get Library Instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance), and then use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to get the values.

For example, consider a library named MyLibrary.py:

```
# MyLibrary.py
foo = "this is foo"

class MyClass(object):
    bar = "this is bar"
```

You can access foo and bar by using [Get Library Instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance) to get a handle to the library:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | MyLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of accessing variables in a library
| | ${lib}= | Get Library Instance | MyLibrary
| | 
| | Should be equal as strings | ${lib.foo} | this is foo
| | Should be equal as strings | ${lib.MyClass.bar} | this is bar
```

Comment: So even with the ${object.variable} access capability in robotframework, it does not apply to "libraries" only objects?

Comment: @kimon: after thinking a bit more about this problem I came up with a solution. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'` to MyClass. If not `Get Library Instance` will create second instance of the MyClass.